# Show All Instances That Should Be Dynamically Registered With a Listener

Tags: database, oracle

Is there a way in Oracle to show which instances should dynamically register by default with a certain listener?

I can do

lsnrctl status | grep Instance

and this will show me the currently running instances that are registered with that particular listener. But this will not display the instances that are not running.

In more detail:

Lets assume I have:

INSTDEV1 (up), INSTDEV2 (up), INSTDEV3 (down) registered with LISTENER_HOST1_DEV

and INSTSTG1 (up), INSTSTG2 (up), INSTSTG3 (down) registered with LISTENER_HOST1_STG

Is there a straightforward way to find out that the first three instances should register with LISTENER_HOST1_DEV
and the second set - with LISTENER_HOST1_STG

lsnrctl status LISTENER_HOST1_DEV & lsnrctl status LISTENER_HOST1_STG will show  only INSTDEV1,  INSTDEV2, INSTSTG1 and INSTSTG2, not the non-running instances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1st way:

You can check oratab file at
/etc/oratab or /var/opt/oracle/oratab
For all the instances

And login to each of the database and check for the local_listener parameter is defined or not.

show parameter local_list

It will be defined in Dynamic mode.

2nd way:

If you have created 12c database with dynamic listener option your tnsnames.ora file will have separate listener entries defined for each database in the format 
LISTENER_SID along with your tnsentries

I don't know of any other method.
Hope this helps.